# Notification Dropbox API Android

Tags: android, notifications, dropbox-api

I'm trying to implements notifications for an Android application : I am using Dropbox API : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps. 
I've never done something like that, i have read a bit about that i should use a JSON request ? I have not found any tutorial related to notification with dropbox api for android.

Which steps should I follow etc?

Comment: Can you tell me more about your application? What are you trying to build?

Comment: I can download file on my app via Dropbox api. Now i wanted to send notification to the smartphone when i post à new file in my Dropbox account

Answer (score 0):

**1. Get changes**

Call [/detal API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#delta) periodically to get changes in DropBox.

To call API, [Dropbox's Java Library](http://dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#overview) maybe helps.

You can schedule periodical task with below:

- [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). (outdated)
- [JobScheduler API](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html). (support Lollipop or higher)
- [GcmNetworkManager](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-gcmnetworkmanager) (support Lollipop and pre-Lollipop)

**2. Show Notificasion**

Show Notification when same changes is happend.
Here is [official documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: Hello nshmura
Thanks for your response the point is I don't understand i should i call https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/delta i'm not familiar with managing url at all whit the method post ? and i pass parameter ?
Should i be connected first ?

Comment: @PierreColombo I recommed you to use retrofit to post a request to dropbox api http://square.github.io/retrofit/ . it is easy to use.

Comment: i'm not familiar at all with json request on the internet i found something about Models ? Should i generate one ? how can i pass argument to this url https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/delta ?

Comment: I've try something like that :

Comment: Oh, I found Dropbox API library: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#overview . This library maybe helps.

Comment: I cannot call it because android studio says POST is not applicable to type :/

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

NotificationInterface service = retrofit.create(NotificationInterface.class);

and then i've panned to create the request object :
NotificationRequest request = new NotificationRequest()

and i don't know what to set in the cursor or the local or in the include_media_info .

Comment: Ja i use this dropbox API :) but they don't speak about notification in this api :'(

Comment: I think you can do like following: 1. Use Dropbox's Java Library to get changes on dropbox. 2. Show Notification by your java program.

Comment: I don't understand how the jobscheduler works :
i have created my jobservice but i should start it only if i get a change in my liste ? and then if the jobservice starts i should trigger a notification but where i put the code in onStartJob ?

Comment: `GcmNetworkManager` maybe more fit your situation: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-gcmnetworkmanager . I just glanced, but I guess it is easy to use.

Comment: I've used a service with a timer :
Basically this is my strategie (i'm using https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core ) : -calling delta/last_cursor to get a cursor -calling long_poll_data with this cursor as parameter
Thanks for you help .
For my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231698/android-using-dropboxapi-to-know-if-there-are-changes-in-my-dropbox-api

Answer (score 0):

I've try something like that : 3 classes

```
public interface NotificationInterface {
@POST("1/delta");
Call<NotificationResponse> getNotificationResponse(@Body NotificationRequest request);
}

public class NotificationRequest {
    private String cursor;
    private String local;
    //path_prefix won't be present

    private String include_media_info;
}
public class NotificationResponse {

    @SerializedName("entries")
    @Expose
    private String entries;

    @SerializedName("reset")
    @Expose
    private String reser;


    @SerializedName("cursor")
    @Expose
    private String cursor;

    @SerializedName("has_more")
    @Expose
    private String has_more; }
```

Am I on the right way ? I try to use https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#access-token and http://square.github.io/retrofit/ to get notification as you suggest :)

The point is post cannot be applied to 1/delta ! What is wrong with my code ?

Thanks for your help !