# Android: using Dropbox API to know if there are changes in my Dropbox

Tags: java, android, notifications, dropbox-api

I'm trying to know if there are changes in my Dropbox. Basically this is my strategy (I'm using https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core ):

- calling delta/last_cursor to get a cursor
- calling long_poll_data with this cursor as parameter

  ```
             /// I use RESTUtility and i've tried to adapt this code : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility
             /// example  : 8 for last_cursor
             /// example : 13 for longpoll_delta

             /// https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#delta
             // we use first the method : /delta/latest_cursor to get a cursor

             Log.d(" NotificationService", " ================================Finding latest cursor");
             ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
             params.add("include_media_info");
             params.add("false"); // if true there is a mistake
             Object response = RESTUtility.request(RESTUtility.RequestMethod.POST, "api.dropbox.com", "delta/latest_cursor", 1, params.toArray(new String[params.size()]), mDBApi.getSession());

             /// Preparation of the cursor to use longpoll_ delta

             // response.toString() look like that : {"cursor":"AAGwyo3TijR4_dgBxCj8LrU-NBO5ET7xipVxMl_vGMn-O7PKemycTBR3FpK57856J-vTtn5wyNyzwJaaGlKn2h2o5gv8lBFzQ6Hn9KgdDHi7uH77boLG2Y1GOT1VgnWyxMU"}
             Log.d(" NotificationService", " ================================First cursor avant le substring : " + response.toString());
             // lastestCursor look lije that : AAGwyo3TijR4_dgBxCj8LrU-NBO5ET7xipVxMl_vGMn-O7PKemycTBR3FpK57856J-vTtn5wyNyzwJaaGlKn2h2o5gv8lBFzQ6Hn9KgdDHi7uH77boLG2Y1GOT1VgnWyxMU
             latestCursor = response.toString().substring(11, response.toString().length() - 2);
             Log.d(" NotificationService", " ================================First cursor: " + latestCursor);

             //Try to use longpoll_delta to know if {"changes": false, "backoff": 60} changes is true

             ArrayList<String> paramsLongpoll_delta = new ArrayList<>();
             paramsLongpoll_delta.add("cursor");
             paramsLongpoll_delta.add(latestCursor);
             paramsLongpoll_delta.add("timeout");
             paramsLongpoll_delta.add("120");

             Object responseLongpoll_delta = RESTUtility.request(RESTUtility.RequestMethod.GET, "api-notify.dropbox.com", "longpoll_delta", 1, paramsLongpoll_delta.toArray(new String[paramsLongpoll_delta.size()]), mDBApi.getSession());
             Log.d(" NotificationService", " ================================Second Cursor: " + responseLongpoll_delta.toString());

          } catch (DropboxException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  });
  interrogateTheServerTask.start();
  ```

The point is: I get the response for the first call.
But for the second I get this answer:

```
08-30 17:11:57.706 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err: com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(Unknown Source)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(Unknown Source)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(Unknown Source)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.request(Unknown Source)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.example.colombop.ble.NotificationService$2.run(NotificationService.java:161)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:705)
08-30 17:11:57.707 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:108)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:196)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:88)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:179)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:185)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:240)
08-30 17:11:57.708 31971-32681/com.example.colombop.ble W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:264)
```

Does anybody has a suggestion?

Comment: The longpoll function by definition uses a long-held connection to wait for changes. You're telling the API to hold that for up to 120 seconds, but that's apparently longer than the default socket timeout. You may want to try using a shorter timeout parameter, or using a longer socket timeout, e.g., perhaps by using this [`execute`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/RESTUtility.html#execute(com.dropbox.client2.session.Session,%20org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20int)) method instead.

Comment: However, Dropbox [API v1 is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) anyway, so I'd recommend just using the [API v2 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java) instead: [`listFolderGetLatestCursor`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderGetLatestCursor-java.lang.String-) and [`listFolderLongpoll`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderLongpoll-java.lang.String-long-).